# When is it ok to add two separate answers?

Tags: discussion

When, if ever, is it ok to add more than one answer? I was acrually thinking about how to add clarity to [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/34942/import-vector-data-into-illustrator) question by splitting my answer in two parts.

- the use EPS part
- other methods part

is that ok? Or maybe i just went totally overboard? And should trim the ansver just to the eps part.

Another thing, should the answer actually belong to stackoverflow? I mean it is a general programming question involving illustrator. While i feel it may have merit on this site, after all a designer might have this need. But its on the edge. Any thoughts?

### Edit:

I did split the answer in 2, but refrained form splitting the answer into 3 separate entries. So now its a split between programmatic access and file format compatibility. If any body has some comments on that they are welcome. But now I found a new pet project (seems like there's lots of questions up my alley this week).

Anybody care to comment on the suitability fo the post on GE versus stack overflow/super user?

Comment: Sometimes a there are multiple questions disguised as one: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/how-do-i-get-this-uneven-airbrush-effect-similar-to-old-art-deco-posters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think user568458 covered it nicely, but to add a small anecdote: There was one answer I posted some time ago (I forget which one) that included two different solutions in a single post. A short while later the OP had asked for some clarification in the comments, they has apparently confused the steps as one big answer.

Since then I've not felt guilty about posting two answers for separate methods. The compartmentalization makes things easier to follow, so I'd encourage others to do the same.

Comment: Yeah that why i split it. I looked at the post you did and tough about it hard. Describing EPS then postscript seems appropriate (after all its a direct descendant),  describing COM and javascript not so much.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, put two answers when there are two completely different methods that are both valid with different independent advantages. In your case, one long answer looks like it makes more sense since they relate to each other, and you refer to the EPS when talking about the other.

Here's [an example of a question where JohnB posted two answers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-do-i-make-an-incomplete-circle-stroke-for-a-donut-chart) because there were two completely different techniques that both had pros and cons.

Comment: Okay this didn't resolve the situation really since while generating say a PDF is related to generating a EPS to some degree were i to show the process i would not need to reference the step. In any case using scripting engines may then warrant a second answer? Okay.